# C++/CLI Interop: COM function always returns null IntPtr

Tags: com, interop, c++-cli

I have C++/CLI module which uses COM library. COM library function returns pointer to the object. Signature of the COM function call in C++/CLI is like this

```
          IntPtr p = myCOMObject->GetSettings();
```

In COM interface same function has the following singnature

```
         virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSettings( 
        /* [retval][out] */ void *CSettings) = 0;
```

argument object *CSettings is native C++ object of some other class created in side GetSettings function.

When call this function in C++/CLI. I always Get IntPtr as '0' and no value set to it. I checked with pure C++ code, I get proper object. what could be the reason for this.Am i doing somthing wrong please suggest.

Comment: If `CSettings` is `[retval][out]`, shouldn't it be declared `void**`?

Comment: Event if I changed to Void**.. I am getting same result.

Comment: Tim is right, this signature is fundamentally flawed.  You can't just change it without also changing the COM server.  I'm pretty sure I already answered this question btw, post a link to your other question or username.

Comment: Hi Hans you are right, I have done changes on the COM Server part as well as on the usage part for Void **, but I am getting pointer as always zero that is IntPtr = 0;

Comment: In C++ the `[out]` in the function signature is just a comment. When your C++ variable is `void **CSettings` you assign to it by writing `*CSettings = value;` **not** `CSettings = value;` as you would do in C# (where [out] variables are passed byref).